# Losses of first buffered data of mp3 decoding using MediaCodec in android-NDK 10 version

Tags: android-ndk, mp3, decoding, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I use [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) and MediaExtractor classes from android NDK for decoding mp3 files. For comparison input file(mp3) and outputfile(wav - it`s my decoded format) i look at tracks duration and i exactly see difference of duration 50 milliseconds. I check it on anothers tracks and this difference always present. So, i lost first near 50 milliseconds of my input track.

Algorithm of decoding used like in androin ndk-samples(native-codec) decoding fragment is below

```
ssize_t bufidx = -1;
if (!d->sawInputEOS) 
{
    bufidx = AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer(codec, 2000);
    LOGV("input buffer %zd", bufidx);
    if (bufidx >= 0) 
    {
        size_t bufsize;
        uint8_t *buf = AMediaCodec_getInputBuffer(codec, bufidx, &bufsize);
        ssize_t sampleSize = AMediaExtractor_readSampleData(ex, buf, bufsize);
        if (sampleSize < 0) 
        {
            sampleSize = 0;
            d->sawInputEOS = true;
            LOGV("EOS");
        }
        int64_t presentationTimeUs = AMediaExtractor_getSampleTime(extractor);
        AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer(codec, bufidx, 0, sampleSize, presentationTimeUs,
d->sawInputEOS ? AMEDIACODEC_BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);
        AMediaExtractor_advance(ex);
    }
}
if (!d->sawOutputEOS) 
{
    AMediaCodecBufferInfo info;
    ssize_t status = AMediaCodec_dequeueOutputBuffer(codec, &info, 0);
    if (status >= 0) 
    {
        if (info.flags & AMEDIACODEC_BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) 
        {
            LOGV("output EOS");
            d->sawOutputEOS = true;
        }

    AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer(codec, status, info.size != 0);
} 
else if (status == AMEDIACODEC_INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
LOGV("output buffers changed");
} else if (status == AMEDIACODEC_INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
AMediaFormat *format = NULL;
format = AMediaCodec_getOutputFormat(d->codec);
LOGV("format changed to: %s", AMediaFormat_toString(format));
AMediaFormat_delete(format);
} else if (status == AMEDIACODEC_INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
LOGV("no output buffer right now");
} else {
LOGV("unexpected info code: %zd", status);
}
```

}

This code provided with "native codec" sample in NDK.

How can i fix it? because of loss data are unacceptable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not read out buffered frames from decoder. When you leaves the decoding loop you need to check for dequeueOutputBuffer till the flag BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM on the BufferInfo returned in dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.BufferInfo, long)

> Once the client reaches the end of the input data it signals the end
>   of the input stream by specifying a flag of BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM
>   in the call to queueInputBuffer(int, int, int, long, int). The codec
>   will continue to return output buffers until it eventually signals the
>   end of the output stream by specifying the same flag
>   (BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) on the BufferInfo returned in
>   dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.BufferInfo, long). Do not submit
>   additional input buffers after signaling the end of the input stream,
>   unless the codec has been flushed, or stopped and restarted.

Comment: i did`t submit additional input buffers i check it by flag    if (!d->sawInputEOS).  For Details i open input and output files in the "audacity" And i have seen the problem is in output file - the start 50 ms is lost, and other sound-signal buffers will be displaced to begining of track of same 50ms. And i think problem is not with using BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM.